# why doesn't 0 == (0 or 1) return True

Tags: python

My original bit of python was:

```
if i.count('<') and i.count('>') == (0 or 1):
    pass
else:
    print('error')
```

This passes with **i = '<>'** and fails with **i = '<>>'** which is what I want. However it also fails with **i = ''** which I don't want and can't understand.

In ipython3 i've fiddled with this long enough to come down to the abstracted

```
0 == (0 or 1)
```

which strangely returns False. I'm guessing it has something to do with 0=False 1=True, but even after quite a bit of googleing it still doesn't quite make sense to me.

Do I really have to rewrite my original code to the much longer and to my mind uglier:

```
(i.count('<') and i.count('>') == 0) or (i.count('<') and i.count('>') == 1)
```

Comment: Your longer version is also wrong because you're using `and` incorrectly just as you were using `or` incorrectly.

Comment: Really not sure what the `and` and `or` use is here... `if i.count('<') != i.count('>')` is surely what your first attempt would have been....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0 or 1` is always evaluated to `1` (The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned. -- from [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations))

```
>>> 0 or 1
1
```

`0 == (0 or 1)` is equivalent to `0 == 1` -> `False`.

To check whether x is `0` or `1`, do the following:

```
x == 0 or x == 1
```

or

```
x in (0, 1)
```

Comment: ``0 <= x <= 1`` (python can do that)

Comment: Thanks. "x in (0, 1)" will do the trick nicely, however while I accept that "0 or 1" was being evaluated to 1, I still don't really understand why.

Comment: @vorpal, Did you read the sentences inside the parentheses at the first line of my answer?

Comment: @vorpal, `0` is treated as false when used as predicate.

Comment: @falsetru was that an edit? I swear it wasn't there when I first read it. Thanks again.

Comment: @vorpal, Yes, it was an edit. Those sentences are not there at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`(0 or 1)` is evaluated to `1`, `0 == 1` is evaluated to `False`